# Div not being created n amount of times from for loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm trying to create a div as many times as is entered in an input field (in the div "controls left" with the name "quantity).

I've created a for loop to append the child divs to the parent div but nothing is happening?

this is the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <script src="task3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task3.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Practical Excercise 3 - Part 3</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="main" class="container">
            <button class="right" onclick="menuClick()">MENU</button>
            <h1>Part 3 - Javascript Playground</h1>
            <div id="mcount" onmouseover="mousePassCtr()"></div>
            <div id="posts">

            </div>
            <hr />
            <textarea id="text-content" rows="4" cols="60">Type your text here...</textarea>
            <br />
            <div class="controls left">
                <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" /><br />
                <input id="blue" type="radio" name="color" value="blue" /> Blue<br />
                <input id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="red" /> Red<br />
                <button onclick="postClick()">Post</button>
            </div>
            <div class="controls left">
                <input type="range" name="visible" min="1" max="10" value="10"/><br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="style" value="bold" /> Bold<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="style" value="italic" /> Italic<br />
                <select>
                    <option disabled selected value="-1">Choose a post to reply to</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>

        <div id="menu" class="container" style="display:none;">
            <button class="right" onclick="backClick()">BACK</button>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <span>Background Color:</span><input type="text">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

this is the js

```js
function postClick() {

    var mainPostDiv = document.getElementById("posts"); // Creating variable for the main post div

    // Creating a date paragraph within the HTML doc and appending it with the date of the post
    var dateDiv = document.createElement('P'); // creating the date div
    dateDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-time"); // setting the class of the div
    var date = new Date(); // initializing time of posts date to date variable
    var dateLocale = date.toLocaleString(); // converting the date to a locale version and to a string
    var dateTimeNode = document.createTextNode(dateLocale); // creating a node on DOM tree with the locale date in it
    dateDiv.style.fontWeight = "bold";  // changing the dates font-weight to bold
    dateDiv.style.color ="grey"; // changing the dates font-color to grey
    dateDiv.appendChild(dateTimeNode); // appending the date node to the date div

    // Creating a content paragraph and appending it with the content within the input field
    var contentDiv = document.createElement('P'); // creating the content div
    contentDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-content"); // setting the class of the div
    var content = document.getElementById("text-content").value; // getting the value inside of the input field and assigning it to content
    var contentNode = document.createTextNode(content); // creating a node containing the content value
    contentDiv.appendChild(contentNode); // apending the content node to the content div

    var postNum = document.getElementsByName("quantity").value;
    var blueChecker = document.getElementById("blue");
    var redChecker = document.getElementById("red");

    for (var i = 0; i < postNum; i++) {
        mainPostDiv.appendChild(dateDiv);
        mainPostDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    }





}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this

```
var postNum = document.getElementsByName("quantity").value;
```

Like that

```
var postNum = document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']").value;
```

Because getElementsByName() method of the Document object returns a **collection** of NodeList elements with the given name

Move the code for creating dateDiv and contentDiv into a for loop like this

```
var mainPostDiv = document.getElementById("posts"); // Creating variable for the main post div

var postNum = document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']").value;
var blueChecker = document.getElementById("blue");
var redChecker = document.getElementById("red");

for (var i = 0; i < postNum; i++) {
        // Creating a date paragraph within the HTML doc and appending it with the date of the post
        var dateDiv = document.createElement('P'); // creating the date div
        dateDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-time"); // setting the class of the div
        var date = new Date(); // initializing time of posts date to date variable
        var dateLocale = date.toLocaleString(); // converting the date to a locale version and to a string
        var dateTimeNode = document.createTextNode(dateLocale); // creating a node on DOM tree with the locale date in it
        dateDiv.style.fontWeight = "bold";  // changing the dates font-weight to bold
        dateDiv.style.color = "grey"; // changing the dates font-color to grey
        dateDiv.appendChild(dateTimeNode); // appending the date node to the date div

        // Creating a content paragraph and appending it with the content within the input field
        var contentDiv = document.createElement('P'); // creating the content div
        contentDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-content"); // setting the class of the div
        var content = document.getElementById("text-content").value; // getting the value inside of the input field and assigning it to content
        var contentNode = document.createTextNode(content); // creating a node containing the content value
        contentDiv.appendChild(contentNode); // apending the content node to the content div
        mainPostDiv.appendChild(dateDiv);
        mainPostDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
}
```

Comment: Still happens to only display the divs once each, the for loop isn't doing anything and im not sure why

Comment: Move the code for creating dateDiv and contentDiv into a for loop

Comment: Works just fine... see fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/e9ojsmbL/](https://jsfiddle.net/e9ojsmbL/)
It prints the post as many times as i set in the quantity field. (But as a `<p>`) if you want to have multiple `<div>`s you need to create them like you create the `<p>`

Comment: @AntonDikarev what is queryselector compared to getelementbyname? thanks :)

Comment: getElementsByName only selects elements based on their name. querySelector can use any selector which gives it much more flexibility and power, but it is newer and so has weaker browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the first element from `document.getElementsByName("quantity")`, as it returns an array of elements. Change it to `var postNum = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[0].value;` so that you can have the value of the first element

Comment: It still only prints it once, postNums is a value that is inputted and it is supposed to print the divs that many times. even without the [0].values it works, but the issue is that it isnt printing that amount out in the for loop

Comment: Without you selecting the value of the specific element, how would your loop run when the end condition of the loop `postNum` is `undefined`? For your loop to run, you need to assign an integer value to `postNum`. Run `console.log(postNum)` before the loop to check the value with your current implementation